# Apache Internal Rewrite to Vhost

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have an Apache server with 2 vhosts - vhost1 (1.2.3.4) and vhost2 (5.6.7.8).
I want to know if its possible to internally rewrite a URL from vhost1 to vhost2 without sending a 301 to the client? I dont mind that the URL will not change for the client, but I want to know if this is possible?

Both vhosts are bound to different IP addresses on port 80.

Currently vhost1 has the following RewriteRule

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 5.6.7.8:80>

</VirtualHost>
```

and example.com maps to vhost2.
I want to send this directly (internally) to vhost2 without generating a 301 back to the client. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Are thay using the same webspace? If yes than you can if not than you can try it with a alias

Comment: You can try with `P` flag: `[P,NE,L]`

Comment: Thanks. So by using the P flag does my rewrite rule send to the IP or the domain? Will the request be sent over the network or will the OS realise 5.6.7.8 is local...